# How can I create a sparse matrix as a list of lists? (C++)

Tags: c++, templates

The question is: Is it possible to create a sparse matrix using the following sparse list implementation? In special, using a class template with a class template (SparseList*>)?

I've created a class template named SparseList where I can add elements in whatever index I want.

I'd like to use it to create a SparseMatrix class template. So I tried the following...

```
//SparseMatrix.h

template <typename T>
class SparseMatrix {
    public:
        SparseMatrix();

    private:
        SparseList<SparseList<T>*> *matrix; 
};

template <typename T>
SparseMatrix<T>::SparseMatrix() {
    matrix = new SparseList<SparseList<T>*>();
}
```

But when I try to instantiate it on main...

```
int main() {
    SparseMatrix<int> *matrix;
    matrix = new SparseMatrix<int>(); //without this line it compiled normally.

    return 0;
}
```

I got the following error...

```
In file included from src/main.cpp:
SparseMatrix.h:   instantiated from 'SparseMatrix<T>::SparseMatrix() [with T = int]'
main.cpp:   instantiated from here
SparseList.h: error: template argument required for 'struct SparseMatrix'
```

I'm using NetBeansIDE 6.9.1 with MinGW.

EDIT:

```
//SparseList.h
template <typename T>
class SparseList {

    template <typename U>
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &output, const SparseList<U> &list);

public:
    SparseList();
    virtual ~SparseList();

    void insert(T &entry, int index);
    T & get(int i);
    int length();

private:
    struct ListNode {
        int index;
        T *entry;
        ListNode *next;
    };

    ListNode *head; //pointer to the first entry in the sparse list.
    int size; //# of entries.
};
```

I already tested inserts and gets, constructors and destructors, everything in the SparseList. Working fine... =)

Comment: Don't say `new` for no reason. In fact, don't say `new`, period. Also, why do you have a list of lists? Wouldn't a map of pairs (i,j) to values be more appropriate?

Comment: I don't understand... what do you mean with "Don't say new for no reason".
Well... never thought of that. Don't know how to use maps. I'll take a look at that. Thank you. =)

Comment: Just don't say new. Why would you? You could just say `SpareMatrix<int> matrix;` in your main function.

Comment: The code you provided is [minimally compilable](http://ideone.com/2DzKg), modulo a SparseList definition. So there is more going on than shown.

Comment: can you please include the code of `SparseList.h` so that i can compile and see what is the error.

Comment: Maybe provide us with the rest of the code, i.e. `SparseList.h` etc. Further to Kerrek's comments, sparse matrices are not usually implemented as linked-lists, a popular data structure is the compressed column (or row) storage scheme.

Comment: Your code is once again [compilable](http://ideone.com/eSCdk) **except** that `ListNode *head,` uses a comma where a semicolon is expected.

Comment: My bad.... Just corrected.
@Aditya Kumar, I'm taking a look at RCS and CCS right now. Thanks for the advice. =)

Answer (score 2):

Why all the pointers?

This should do the job as your data storage inside your class:

```
std::map<std::pair<I, I>, T>
```

Where `I` is your index type (e.g. `int`) and `T` is your number type (e.g. double).

Or you could just use [`compressed_matrix`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix_sparse.htm#2CompressedMatrix) from `boost::ublas`.